# create "recapitulative" form with infopath?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

I have a question about infopath. I have made a form or people informs diferents number. I would like to create a form that gathers all the data (which adds the values ​​of the different form).

The form is filled out by the users on sharepoint.

more information :

Here is a standard form filled out by users:

[CF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucKS7.jpg)

Users fill in the form, and I would like to generate a recapitulative form with the addition of the entered values
[CF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJOGx.jpg)

Do you know how to make this type of "recapitulative" form?

Thank you for your help
Yours faithfully

Answer (score 0):

The strategy that I recommend is to create two data connections one for all the forms individual data and another one for the Running Totals.  The connection for the Running Total can be another list in SharePoint that will contain the sum for each-field-entry. This will be easier than using merge and a lot faster. The primary data connection will contain the form's normal information (users provided quantities) and will keep track of any changes that need to be sent to the running totals.
Hope it helps!

[InfoPath Form Simulation](http://my.iggy.cloudappsportal.com/Shared%20Documents/Template_Stack_Overflow.xsn)